# Screen flickering in linux on boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I had a perfectly working Ubuntu 21.10 installation but since today, when it boots, the screen just flickers. I thought it might be an issue with the installation so I tried to live boot Ubuntu and Manjaro but the issue persists anyways.

System: Dell Inspiron 3542

Edit: it was working perfectly since the last year, it broke only today after a system update using the Ubuntu's system update utility software and rebooting from there.

Comment: A few questions... do you have a second display you could test with? If it happens in live CDs from multiple distros, you have a hardware issue. Also, and I realize this seems simple, (if it's a desktop) double-check that all the (display) cables are plugged in all the way.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your laptop if it happens with live systems as well. If your are technical and don't have garantee anymore you can open her up. To see if the flexcable is inserted correctly. Damage due to liquid ( corrosion)? (Just asking.) Then clean the connections.

Comment: @cocomac it's a laptop and I don't have access to second display

Comment: @joepiees I shall open it up and see then.

Comment: @humble_barnacle happened to me as well in arch linux multiple live usbs and same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @polmonroig it was due to faulty keyboard which had become rusty causing corrosion. I disconnected the keyboard, reset the system and booted with 20.04 then, although rn I'm using 22.04

Comment: @humble_barnacle thanks for your answer, turns out mine was due to a faulty display port cable, super coincidence since it broke when rebooting